# How I can convert normal SQL query in to doctrine ORM

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I just started studying Symfony 3.4 and Doctrine ORM. I need to take count of users. I tested with the normal query it is working fine. How can I convert the normal query into Doctrine ORM? Any help would be appreciated.

```
"SELECT count(DATE_FORMAT(application.reviewed_at, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS count, user_id FROM application WHERE user_id = 6 AND DATE(reviewed_at) = CURDATE() GROUP BY DATE(reviewed_at)";
```

I tried below code. It is not working.

```
$qb      = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$entries = $qb->select("count(DATE_FORMAT(application.reviewed_at, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS count", "user_id")
            ->where("user_id = 6", "DATE(reviewed_at) = CURDATE()")
            ->from('AppBundle\Entity\Application', 'u');
            ->groupBy("DATE(reviewed_at)");
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

Comment: Describe *not working* - do you get error or unexpected result?

Comment: What's the point doing `count(DATE_FORMAT(application.reviewed_at, '%Y-%m-%d'))` ? You don't care the format since you are counting

Comment: By the way, you don't want to do `AS count` because `count` is already a SQL keyword

Comment: By the way, I doubt your SQL query works actually. `user_id` is not aggregated (else if it's unique, but then, I don't get the point of the query)

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, Doctrine ORM is not intended to transform SQL queries back into DQL. DQL is a query language that can be translated into multiple vendor-specific SQL variants, so this is a one-way transformation from DQL to SQL.

Thus, if you have just a SQL query, it could be a good idea to use just that, [using Doctrine DBAL](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#data-retrieval). Of course, you'd probably have to deal with result set mappings, but there could be no need to drag all the ORM stuff into your code.

What you're doing here is essentially building a DQL query using the Doctrine's `QueryBuilder` API. The `FROM` part is absolutely correct, but those using the `DATE_FORMAT` and `DATE` functions look wrong to me. Since DQL translates to several different SQL implementations, depending on the driver you're using, it needs a compatibility layer because functions such as `DATE_FORMAT`, `DATE` and `CURDATE` are not common for all the platforms.

First, take a look at the [documentation for user-defined functions](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html#date-diff). For example, the `DATEDIFF()` function in MySQL is a good example. If it turns out that no one has already implemented support for the functions you're using, that's a good place to start, since it basically describes how to implement an extension for the Doctrine Query Language (DQL).

Second, there's a good chance that the functions you're using are already implemented in some of the third-party libraries, such as [OroCRM's](https://github.com/oroinc/doctrine-extensions) or [Benjamin Eberlei's](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) Doctrine extension collections.

Also, if you're selecting an aggregation or a function call result, it's always a good idea to alias it. What you could try here is use the `$qb->expr()` function subset to limit the DQL to a more strict grammar.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to remember that Doctrine DQL is **not** an SQL dialect. It is a custom language that attempts to look close to SQL, but it operates with Doctrine entities and associations, not with database tables and columns. Of course at the end it transforms into SQL, but until this transformation you need to stay within DQL syntax.

One of reasons why your query did not work is an attempt to use native SQL (MySQL to be true) functions inside DQL query. DQL have no such functions and you have 2 ways to go at this point:

1. Rewrite your query in a way that it will be compatible with Doctrine. It may involve updates for your database scheme. In your particular case you may want to convert `reviewet_at` column from whatever it is now (`timestamp` I suppose) into `date` type that allows direct date comparisons. It will let you to get rid of custom MySQL date transformation functions and will make your query compatible with Doctrine
2. You can choose a harder path and implement all necessary custom functions directly in Doctrine. It is not a simple thing, but Doctrine is flexible enough to provide you with such ability. There is [good article](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html#dql-user-defined-functions) into Doctrine documentation about this topic if you will be interested.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give a go to this:

```
public function select()
{
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');

    $queryBuilder
        ->addSelect(['a.user_id', $queryBuilder->expr()->count('a.reviewed_at')])
        ->where('a.user_id = :idUser')
        ->andWhere('a.reviewed_at = :date')
        ->setParameters([
            'idUser' => 6,
            'date' => new \DateTime(),
        ])
        ->groupBy('a.reviewed_at')
    ;

    return $queryBuilder
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```